# How do I create a LCM tree diagram?

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to create a [LCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) tree diagram which looks something like this:

[image: http://static.prometheanplanet.com/images/resources/resource-thumbnails/thumb-nprealg-04-01-0002-diagram-thumb-lg-png.png]

Also what is the code to draw circles around numbers?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Thank you all from the bottom of my heart! I know my students will appreciate these worksheets that you guys helped designed

Answer (score 12):

With my `tikz`-based package [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest), this can be achieved in a very concise way:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} mark/.style={circle,draw=red}
  [8[2,mark][4[2,mark][2,mark]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This [forest](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) package looks like serious business!...

Comment: @CountZero tnx! it did take a serious amount of time to write it ... :-)

Comment: Congratulations and a big thank you for you contribution. Can you please add your details in here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here ? You can use the proper icon for the dev-page.

Comment: Thanks. Added --- great idea having such a page! I didn't use the icon since [forest-styles](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles) is only a **style** repository.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović `forest` is indeed a very nice package.  I'm wondering why you decided not to use the `qtree` `.label` syntax for node labels.  I've got lots of legacy trees, so that switching to `forest` would take some effort. Would it be possible to support both styles?

Comment: It was a matter of personal taste, really... I simply prefered `synttree`'s syntax to `qtree`s.  Legacy trees ... "native" support will surely not be possible, because `forest` (like `synttree`) requires every node, including leaves, to be bracketed. It **might** be possible, however, to create a style which would use `forest`'s dynamic tree mechanism to cover the rudimentary `qtree` syntax. I'll think about it...

Comment: @AlanMunn I did it! I believe the issue might be of general interest, so I have posted a self-answered question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95790/is-it-possible-to-emulate-qtree-with-forest  ---  and anyway, one has to advertise his work, right ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Tikz can do nice trees:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \node {8} 
    child { node[circle,draw=red] {2} }
    child { node {4} 
      child { node[circle,draw=red] {2} }
      child { node[circle,draw=red] {2} }
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the obligatory `tikz-qtree` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Red/.style={circle,draw=red}]
\Tree [.8 [.\node[Red] (A){2}; ]
          [.4 
            [.\node [Red] (B) {2}; ]
            [.\node [Red] (C) {2};]]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]