# Is it possible to emulate qtree with forest?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, qtree, forest

This question was actually asked by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) in a comment to [How do I create a LCM tree diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95592/how-do-i-create-a-lcm-tree-diagram). I repeat (and self-answer) it here because the answer is too long to fit the margin :-)

`qtree` is a well-known and heavily used package for drawing trees using the so-called bracket notation. (The bracket notation is especially familiar to linguists.) `forest` is my own, recent package for the same job. Due to the awesome power of `pgf`/`tikz` (in particular, the `pgfkeys` utility), which it is based on, `forest` is an extremely flexible package. ---From the feedback I got so far, including feedback from this site, I don't seem to be the only one who believes so. Which makes me happy. :-)

Although both `qtree` and `forest` encode trees using the bracket notation, the exact syntax is somewhat different. While `forest` requires that each node (including its children) be enclosed in square brackets (like this: `[node [child node] ... [child node]]`), `qtree` relaxes this requirement in the case of terminal nodes (leaves): they can be separated simply by whitespace, like this: `[.node leaf ... leaf ]`.  Furthermore, the packages differ in the encoding of node labels: as showh above, in `qtree` a bracketed (usually non-terminal) node's label must be preceded by a dot (`.`).

(`forest` uses the same syntax as `synttree`; another package that uses (and extends) `qtree`'s syntax is (obviously) `tikz-qtree`. As I mentioned in a comment in the above-mentioned question, I have decided for `synttree`-like syntax purely out of personal taste. I guess I found it more consistent.)

As Alan pointed out, the difference in the syntax makes the potential transition from `qtree` to `forest` harder: nobody wants to throw away tons of trees (s)he has painstakingly drawn. Thus Alan's question: would it be possible for `forest` to support both syntactic dialects?

Answer (score 15):

I'm happy to report that the answer is yes, at least to some extent. I have created a [style](https://raw.github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles/master/forest-qtree.sty) for `forest` which achieves code compatibility: the documents containing `qtree` trees can be used as they are, changing only `\usepackage{qtree}` to `\usepackage{forest-qtree}`.  (Note an exception to this statement: any commas in the node labels must be enclosed in braces; explanation below.) (For the style to work, `forest v1.03` is needed. Since I have just published it today --- yes, I have found some bugs while working on the emulator :-) --- it might not yet be [available at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest); if so, please download it from GitHub: [dtx](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles/raw/master/forest.dtx), [ins](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles/raw/master/forest.ins).)

I have managed to process the `qtree` manual ("forestified" [tex](https://raw.github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles/master/forest-qtreenotes.tex), [pdf](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles/raw/master/forest-qtreenotes.pdf)) with the emulator, omitting only the trees exemplifying `qtree`'s low-level interface.  In detail, the emulation covers the `[.label child ... [.subtree ...] child ... child ].label` syntax, `\qroof`s, invocation via `\Tree`, label-less nodes, sub- and superscripts and primes, hooks, escapes, subtree framing, and centering (on the fly and the package options).  Essentially, only the length parameters and spacing adjustments are not emulated; and as far as the latter are concerned, I believe that `forest` (due to its positioning algorithm) does not really need them. ;-)

There is also a dark side to the story, though.

First, the emulation does *not* produce a visually identical result. The structure of the resulting trees is the same, but the typesetting details are not. This could be improved upon, but I have refrained from doing so, since I believe that the best choice of formatting parameters producing the desired effect(s) will differ from document to document.

Second, the emulation might ease the *transition*, but it certainly wouldn't be practical to use it in new code. Let me explain.

Assume we have a node containing two leaves. `forest` representation: `[node [child1] [child2]]` (spaces between nodes are irrelevant); `qtree` representation: `[.node child1 child2 ]` (spaces relevant!). Verdict: `qtree`'s version is easier to write. However ...

... assume we want to put the first child in a frame. In `forest`, this is achieved by specifying `draw` on the node (this `draw` is simply forwarded to `tikz`'s `\node`), like this: `[node [child1,draw] [child2]]`. An attempt to do the same in the `qtree` emulation will fail: `[.node child1,draw child2 ]` fails with a "unknown key `draw child2`" error (child1 is typeset, but not framed).  This is so because `forest` uses `pgfkeys` to parse node-specifications and in `pgfkeys`, keys are separated by commas. There is no way around this: one must write `[.node {child1,draw} child2 ]`, which obviously eliminates the original advantage of `qtree`-like syntax; the only thing achieved is that one must change braces to brackets if he decides to give child1 children of its own ...

Btw, emulation obviously also carries a performance penalty, and furthermore, since it is implemented by changing the geometry of the tree on the fly (yes, `forest` can do that!), this can easily lead to interferences in trees formatted using complex styles.

Comment: Thanks for this, Sašo. We actually focused on two different aspects of the `qtree` syntax: for you the lack of brackets for terminals, for me, only the `.` in labels. (In my own trees I tend to bracket terminals anyway.)  So the issue of grouping isn't too important for me although it might be for others. Also, as a side note, I suspect many `qtree` users are already using `tikz-qtree` which also doesn't need some of the low level `qtree` commands. Thanks again.  Your package is very impressive.

Comment: I see! Well, I hope it will be useful to someone nevertheless. It was for me: I found three bugs!   If you're really sure you have all nodes bracketed, then the solution is actually very simple. Assuming that `\removedot` is an expandable macro removing the initial dot, `delay={for tree={content={\removedot{#1}}}}` in the tree's preamble will do the trick.

Comment: Cool. I'll try that.