# Drawing a LISP expression as a tree

Tags: tikz-trees

Somewhat inspired by [How to automatically draw tree diagram of prime factorization with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131689) and mostly motivated by laziness, I'd like to be able to draw a tree defined by LISP syntax for a class I'll be TA'ing next semester.

For those who don't know, LISP is a programming language (the second oldest, in fact) that specifies programs directly as trees:

```lisp
(defun count (a l &optional c)
  (if l                                      ;; if l is not empty [()===nil]
      (count a                               ;; return the number of a's in the cdr
             (cdr l)
             (+ (if c c 0)                   ;; add c (if it wasn't given, start with 0)
                (if (equal a (car l)) 1 0))) ;; and 1 or 0, if a==l[0]
    c))                                      ;; otherwise, return the count
```

Given the `(if ...)` sequence, I'd like it to come up with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{10pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 10cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node  {if}
    child{ node {l} }
    child{ node {count}
            child{ node {a} }
            child{ node {cdr}
                    child{node {l}}}
            child{ node {+}
                            child{ node {if}
                                child { node {c} }
                                child { node {c} }
                                child { node {0} }}
                            child{ node {if}
                                child { node {equal}
                                    child {node {a}}
                                    child {node {car}
                                        child { node {l}}}}
                                child { node {1}}
                                child { node {0}}}}}
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously the style is whatever looks best, but I'd like the macro to avoid the crossings that my example is a victim of.

[image]

My best guesses are to make `(` and `)` active somehow, but I don't have the TeXnical experience to define such macros off-hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the following solutions can work with a literal `&` and

```
\catcode`\&=12
```

## `forest` + `xstring`

A proof of concept that uses `xstring` to split things at spaces. Unfortunately, setting the `opening bracket` and the `closing bracket` didn’t work for me so a quick Search’n’Replace will be needed.

The `afterthough` key is redefined so that everything after a child and the next closing `]` is forwarded to the `splitter*` key.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,xstring}
\forestset{
  splitter/.code={%
    \fullexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{\forestov{content}}{ }{%
      \StrCount{\forestove{content}}{ }[\cnt]%
      \def\forestPrepend{}%
      \foreach \Cnt[evaluate={\CNT=int(\Cnt+1)}] in {\cnt,...,1} {%
        \StrBetween[\Cnt,\CNT]{\forestov{content} }{ }{ }[\tmp]%
        \xappto\forestPrepend{,prepend={[\expandonce\tmp]}}%
      }%
      \expandafter\forestset\expandafter{\forestPrepend}%
      \StrBefore{\forestov{content}}{ }[\forestContent]%
      \forestolet{content}\forestContent%
    }{}},
  splitter*/.code={%
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{ #1}{ }{%
      \StrCount{ #1}{ }[\cnt]%
      \def\forestAppend{}%
      \foreach \Cnt[evaluate={\CNT=int(\Cnt+1)}] in {1,...,\cnt} {%
        \StrBetween[\Cnt,\CNT]{ #1 }{ }{ }[\tmp]%
        \xappto\forestAppend{,append={[\expandonce\tmp]}}%
      }%
      \expandafter\forestset\expandafter{\forestAppend}
    }{}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\begin{forest}  for tree={delay=splitter, afterthought/.style={for parent={splitter*={#1}}}}
[defun count [a l \&optional c]
  [if l
      [count a
             [cdr l]
             [+ [if c c 0]
                [if [equal a [car l] ] 1 0]]]
    c]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## `forest-qtree`

With the excellent setup of the [`forest-qtree.sty`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95790/16595) file from the author of forest himself and a small change (that may be needed again at other places), it is even easier. Unfortunately, setting the brackets to `(` and `)` hasn’t worked out for me so far.

For some reason, `standalone` outputs one big empty page before and one page the size of the tree after the actual tree …

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest-qtree}
\makeatletter
\forestset{
  qtree without dots/.style={% so no empty parent
    qtree,
    /utils/exec=%
      \def\forest@qtree@parse@opening{%
        \@ifnextchar.{\forest@qtree@parse@label}{\forest@qtree@parse@label.}%
      }}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} qtree without dots
[defun count [a l \&optional c]
  [if l
      [count a
             [cdr l]
             [+ [if c c 0]
                [if [equal a [car l] ] 1 0]]]
    c]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `forest` package is your best friend here, since it allows you to specify the bracket that it uses for the tree! However, since it requires all terminals to be bracketed, I needed to adjust the Lisp code to fit that requirement. It's a long time since I've used Lisp, so I might have messed up some things. I also changed the comment characters and escaped the `&`.   More complicated code might encounter other characters that would need to be escaped, but this is proof of concept.  It seems that you could definitely use this method with minimal changes to your Lisp source to generate the appropriate trees.

```
\documentclass[png,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\bracketset{
opening bracket=(,
  closing bracket=)}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
(defun (count) (a (l) (\&optional) (c))
  (if (l)                             % (if) (l) (is) (not) (empty) [()===nil]
    (count (a)                        % (return) (the) (number) (of) (a)'s (in) (the) (cdr)
        (cdr (l))
        (+ (if (c) (c) (0))               % (add) (c) (if (it) (wasn)'t (given), (start) (with) (0))
           (if (equal (a) (car (l))) (1) (0)))) % (and) (1) (or) (0), (if) (a)==l[0]
    (c)))                             % otherwise, return the count
\end{forest} 

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, I just realised that.  `forest` requires terminals to be bracketed, which is the problem.  Hmm. Back to the drawing board, I guess.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel What's needed is a combination of this and [Is it possible to emulate qtree with forest?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95790)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No `forest-qtree` doesn't solve the problem I think, since it also deals with the `.` in the label that `qtree` expects.

Comment: With a small redefinition, `forest-qtree` can be used when we include the `.` if it is not there. See my answer.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Nice.  I didn't have the patience to hunt throught the `forest-qtree` code. :)